# How can I send a text area content to my server?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, servlets, server-side

I have been studying about ajax and this as far as I can get, I would like to send the text area's content to my server and save it in a text file, but I'm a little bit confused on how to do it, BTW my server is apache tomcat. I've heard that I need a piece of code on server side. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = new FormData();
  var cssData = $("#custom-css-text").val();
  data.append("custom_css", cssData);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'myserver',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {value:data},
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
      alert(cssData);

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#custom-css-text {
  border-style: outset;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>

<body>

  <textarea id="custom-css-text">testing</textarea>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You code already sends the data to the server (although the time you do it is a bit odd). You just seem to be missing the server side code. You really should look for a basic servelet tutorial for that.

Comment: I've seen some examples and they look simple, but I don't where to put it. I'll check it out

Comment: You're sending this in `JSON` format so when you're printing it make sure to use `json_encode`. If your server is running PHP that is.

Comment: Actually, that is just an example that is easier to use in a question because all elements are visible, plus it needs to be JSON because I will use it to save the "positions" of a JqTree.

Comment: @ odedta I'm reading about servlets, but will I be able to create a text file with the text area content? as I can see I'll be able to create pretty much anything

Comment: I've downloaded several examples, watched tutorials I even have made several questions asking about it, but it always ends like this, no answer, no clue :(